# How to assemble nested-list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, nested

```
def nested_list(nested):
for i in range (0, len(nested)):
    for k in range (0, len(nested)):
        print(nested[i][k], end = " ")

nested_list([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

> output : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

İt is working.
But when I change `nested_list([[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10]])`like this I get an error. What is the best solution to fix this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: ... or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: Yes sir. But I haven't learned those commands yet. @MauriceMeyer

Comment: What kind of error is printed? Please add the full and exact error message to your question, along with your attempts to resolve that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because your original code assumes "square" list (sublists of the same length like full list).

You need to change inner for loop to check for len of current sublist, not whole list:

```py
def nested_list(nested):
    for i in range(len(nested)):
        for k in range(len(nested[i])): # check len of current sublist
            print(nested[i][k], end = " ")
```

Also changed `range(0, len(nested))` to just `range(len(nested))`. Range works both as `range(start, stop[, step])` (if no step is given, 1 is the default) and `range(stop)` which starts from 0. :)

[range signatures in builtin functions list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), [real description of how range works](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Comment: I understand sir. Thank you :)

Comment: Not a sir. @JackHarmon

Comment: Sorry ma'am. Thank you again

Comment: @JackHarmon Not a ma'am either... It's better to avoid gendered language altogether if you don't know who you're talking to. Especially since English second person is already neutral.

Comment: You are right. I'll pay attention thank you again.

Comment: @h4z3, I've just submitted an edit with a little fix about `range` first parameter. Usefull answer, if I remember well it's less efficient than the `sum` I suggested, but it's more pythonic. +1

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO I tried to modify as little as OP's code as I could because it seems like a learner's code, so I understand why OP might prefer more verbose ranges. ;)

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO I changed it to a longer description on range with links - in case more learners come. And fun fact: range is a class, not a function! (your comment said it's a function :P) And it has two signatures because it's written in C and it's the first argument that has a default value, so cpython devs made it clear with parameter names as well.

Comment: I didn't know that range was a class, I've always thought it was a not-editable iterable, in that case I thought it was a function that returned a tuple. Thank you for the explaination.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast way to do this:

```
nested_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
print(sum(nested_list, []))
```

The `sum` Python's built-in function can be used to "sum" (and in this case to concatenate) the elements in an iterable.

Comment: That's good. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @JackHarmon, I suggest to accept one of the two answers in order to make other users to be sure that the solution proposed are really working.